# Why jwt.io gives me the private key part to fill?

Tags: encryption, jwt, cryptography, rsa, jwt.io

I have a slight confusion regarding the online JWT validator `jwt.io`. As far as I understand, a JWT that is signed with the `RS256` algorithm is signed with a private key, and all is needed to verify it is the corresponding public key.

If so, why is it that `jwt.io` lets you fill in the private key part?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jwt.io works in both directions, you can also add or modify values on the right side (the *Decoded* column) in the header and payload and then get a new signed token if you provide the private key.

As long as you only want to verify an asymmetric signed token, you only need to provide the public key.